# runtime error, strange behaviour

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I wrote a code a simulate a DFA, but it is giving a runtime error because of the cout statement, it runs fine after removing it.

here is the code

```
#include "bits/stdc++.h"
using namespace std;
struct state
{
    char name = ' ';
    bool final=false;
     state *o;
     state *i;
     state *t;
};
int main() {
     state *A,*B,*C,*D,*E,*initial;
    E->final = true;
    A->name='A';
    B->name='B';
    C->name='C';
    D->name='D';
    E->name='E';
    A->o = B;
    A->i = A;
    A->t = B;
    B->o = E;
    B->i = A;
    B->t = C;
    C->o = A;
    C->i = E;
    C->t = D;
    D->o = C;
    D->i = D;
    D->t = E;
    E->o = E;
    E->i = D;
    E->t = A;
    initial = A;
         cout<<(initial->name);
    int p = 5;
    while(p--) {
        cout<<"current state ";
         cout<<(initial->name);
        int a;
        cin>>a;
        if (a==0) initial = initial->o;
        else if (a==1) initial = initial->i;
        else initial = initial->t;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Initial is switching states and telling which state it is currently, it is switching between defined states, so can't understand why there would be missing data

the code is giving runtime error on ideone and segmentation fault on g++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but it is giving a runtime error because of the cout statement

I don't think it has to do with `cout`. Nowhere you create actual objects of type `state`, you just have pointers, and then are dereferencing them (e.g. use of ->), which is not allowed, unless they point to valid objects of corresponding type.

To give more complete answer what you have is undefined behavior, so your program is in invalid state and you can't reason about its behavior. Hence it seems to you that code in `cout` is problem, but problem occurs earlier on first use of `->`.